# Stripe/ Apple Pay/ Rejected by Apple Store

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, applepay

I just submitted an app to app store but rejected by apple, they said the way I show apple pay in the payment option page is not comply with the apple pay icon marketing guide. They said it cannot be an extra "apple pay" next to the apple pay icon.

Unfortunately the above setting is a setting defaulted by stripe pod, is anyone have any idea on how to remove the "Apple pay" word in the select payment option page?

Many thanks!!

[Please see the screenshot as below for your information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JGz.png)

Comment: I think `Stripe` already provides `Apple Pay` option, so you can remove your `Apple Pay` option.

Comment: But I wanted to add apple pay as a payment option.. , do you know how to delete the word "apple pay" in the pod?

I was also trying to remove apple pay option as it has so many limitation from apple, do you know how to remove the apple pay option too?

Comment: I don't know that, but Stripe is also providing Apple Pay option. You can consider that.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/503 might be helpful to you.

Comment: If you want to remove Apple Pay altogether from STPPaymentOptionsViewController, you can configure `STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().additionalPaymentOptions` to `none` so Apple Pay isn't included (it is by default)

Comment: Weird. They let Uber do it the same way you did. https://imgur.com/M9deN3Y

Comment: @hmunoz thank you for the instruction, would you please tell me more about how could I disable the apple pay function? I couldn't find the code you said in the pod..

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes.. it is really weird..

Comment: @Jor https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentConfiguration.html#/c:objc(cs)STPPaymentConfiguration(py)additionalPaymentOptions